# SQL Server 2005 "Pin" data in Memory

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, memory-management, query-optimization

We're running our application's database on dedicated box running only SQL Server 2005. 
This DB server has 32 Gb of RAM... and the database file itself is only 6 Gb.

I'd like to force several of the heavily read/queried tables into the SQL Memory buffer to increase speed.

I understand that SQL server is really good about keeping necessary data cached in memory once it's read from disk... But our clients would probably prefer their query running quickly the FIRST time.
"Fastest Performance the *Second* Time" isn't exactly a product highlight.

Short of the old "Pin Table" DBCC command.. any thoughts?

I've written a "CacheTableToSQLMemory" Proc which Loops through all of a table's Indexes (Clustered & Non) , performing a "Select *" into a Temp table.  I've scheduled SQL Agent to run a "cache lots of tables" Proc every 15 minutes in an attempt to keep pages in Memory.

It works to a large extent.. but even after I cache all of a query's relevant tables, running a query still increased the Count of Cached pages for that table. then it's faster the 2nd time. 
thoughts?

We're running PAE & AWE. SQL is set to use between 8 & 20 GB of RAM.

Comment: 'PAE and AWE set' as in 'I'm still running a crappy x86 instance with 2GB of virtual address space'?

Comment: ... I know... I'm working on pushing an OS upgrade through also...

Comment: What version of Windows? 64-bit I hope, otherwise the answer is _so_ obvious that it's funny

Comment: @smirkingman: 'PAE' implies x86: "PAE is used only by 32-bit versions of Windows running on x86-based systems." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366796%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Good news! Based on everyone's advice, we're testing a Windows Server 2008 x64 & SQL 2008 x64 setup! thanks for the thoughts, all.

Comment: @remus rusanu I know, I was hoping everyone would understand the "funny" allusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The x86 bottleneck is your real issue. AWE can serve only data pages, as they can be mapped in and out of the AWE areas, but every other memory allocation has to cram in the 2GB of the process virtual address space. That would include every thread stack, all the code, all the data currently mappen 'in use' from AWE and, most importantly, every single cached plan, execution plan, cached security token, cached metadata and so on and so forth. and I'm not even counting CLR, I hope you don't use it.

Given that the system has 32GB of RAM, you can't even try /3GB and see if that helps, because of the total PAE reduction to 16GB in that case that would make half your RAM invisible...

You realy, really, have to move to x64. AWE can help only that much. You could collect performance counters from the [Buffer Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189628%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and [Memory Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190924%28SQL.90%29.aspx) objects  and monitor [sys.dm_os_memory_clerks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175019%28SQL.90%29.aspx) so you could get a better picture of how is the instance memory behaving (where does the memory in use go, who is consuming it etc). I don't expect that will help you solve the issue really, but I do expect it will give you enough information to make a case for the upgrade to x64.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to pin tables in memory in SQL Server 2005. If SQL Server is dropping the tables from memory, it's because there is memory pressure from other parts of the system. Since your database is only 6GB, the database should stay in memory... provided that there are no other databases on the server.

There are a few things you can do to try to keep data in memory, though. Depending on the patch level and edition of your SQL Server installation, you might be able to make use of the [lock pages in memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190730%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) functionality to ensure that SQL Server's memory never gets paged out.

You can also change the memory allocation on the server to be a fixed size. Unless there's something else on your database server, you can set SQL Server's min and max memory to the same value. This won't necessarily prevent this from happening in the future (it's a function of how SQL Server is supposed to work) but it certainly won't hurt to set your SQL Server to use a fixed amount of memory (if you have no other memory concerns).